# Do apps like GeekTool cause performance degradation?

Tags: macos, geektool

I started recently using GeekTool and I used some Geeklets for weather, date, and time, things that I had to let it refresh every two or three seconds.

Here is a screenshot of my desktop
[image: screenshot]

I know (but I'm not sure) that this might cause the computer to run slower, but I would like to know if really does cause performance degradation on my Mac?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Activity Monitor, with the active processes sorted by CPU used?

Comment: I've edited your question to replace ‘harm’ with performance degradation, but feel free to rollback if this wasn't the intention of your question.

Comment: Ahh, Activity Monitor from /Applications/Utilities, not your desktop.

Comment: @patrix- yes, using ((Apple scripts)) and ((Terminal commands)).

Comment: Can you please run /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app (just open Spotlight and type "Activity Monitor") and then add a screenshot of the the running processes sorted by CPU? This is the easiest way to see whether any process is using an excess amount of CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that Geektool *can* significantly affect performance on My Macbook Pro (early 2011 running Yosemite).

I've noticed that both Fans start to max out at 6000+ RPM and applications become sluggish. Geektool itself does not appear to be hogging CPU or memory but something related to it is. It's not the geeklets as they are only echoing out some text and running `df -h` every 5 seconds.

One thing I've noticed is that the `WindowServer` process seems to start eating a lot of cpu while Geektool is running. My hunch is that this is the problem - I use my Mac almost exclusively with a large external monitor attached.

So if you do experience performance lag, it may be the individual geeklets if they are doing anything intensive or some combination of Geektool + other applications which need to draw to the screen a lot. Try a search on this site for WindowServer too - there seem to be other people seeing issues with WindowServer causing performance problems on Yosemite.